# Ferrite bead or inductor

Tags: voltage, current, inductor, impedance, ferrite-bead

I'm using this device VSC8514 and this is its [checklist](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/VSC8514-HW-Design-Checklist-00003985.pdf).
I just want to know what spec of ferrite bead I should use for this device's power rails.

They have neither mentioned this in the checklist nor in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/VMDS-10423.pdf).

I went through the Eval board schematic over [here](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/VSC8514EV). They have used an inductor on the Eval board, but in the checklist they mention that a ferrite bead should be used over a series inductor. Not sure which one to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Same as for any ferrite bead application.  Relevant reading: 
[USB 2.0 VBUS Filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648984/usb-2-0-vbus-filter/649064#649064) 
[Ferrite beads for high currents](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433840/ferrite-beads-for-high-currents/647315#647315) 
[Switching PSU and residual noise on the rails](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/306101/switching-psu-and-residual-noise-on-the-rails/306140#306140)

Current consumption varies from 10 to 605 mA depending on rail and activity (datasheet p.70).

Typical ferrite beads saturate in the 20-100 mA range, so would be contraindicated for some of these.  Note a bead's current rating is meaningless: it is ampacity only, a thermal figure, not related to electrical characteristics (or anything beyond DCR at least).

How to find saturation?  Look for the characteristic sheet.  Some manufacturers don't provide them at all; others tuck them away in proprietary databases.  Yes, it's a pain in the ass.

Note that type 2 ceramics are the same way (for the same general reason, actually).  The voltage rating is irrelevant to electrical characteristics; often a part is significantly saturated (-30%, say) at a tiny fraction of its rated voltage.

For this reason, using inductors is often preferable, and mandatory at high currents, and for low cutoff frequencies (read: requires large inductances).  The value of a ferrite bead is its lossiness, saving on a component; this must be substituted with an R+C or R||L network in the filter circuit.  PDN (power distribution network) analysis is probably a bit out of scope here in this question, but are the keywords to look at for further reading.  Typically a lossy "bulk" capacitor provides the damping in such a case.

They also show a ferrite bead in Fig. 4-2 (checklist p.5).  As this is shown shorted out by a capacitor, I suspect they intend these as placement options, with neither, or just one, used in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would this bead help: https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Murata-Electronics/BLM18PG121SN1?qs=%2F7R%2FnUXKGohzfmQaKlrYFw%3D%3D

Comment: Bead saturation is a bit different from inductor saturation because the materials are rather different. Beads are made with highly hysteretic (lossy) material. These naturally have a wide switching field distribution, all the way to rather high currents, so a small fraction remains inductive. Their B(H) curve is an S rather than a Z. They don't saturate as abruptly as inductors and also in contrast to inductors they have mediocre conductivity at HF (eddy losses)

Comment: @Newbie what characteristics does it have?

Comment: @tobalt That's not really true -- they don't exhibit hysteresis any more than other soft ferrites, and indeed the material is sometimes specified (e.g. from Fair-Rite, Laird, etc.). The losses are small-signal in nature, effectively resistance of the core. There are no 'Z' curves among ferroics that I'm aware of (but this isn't much to go on and I would be interested to see more detail regarding this). Saturation sharpness is down to geometry, and indeed the innermost part say of a thick hollow cylinder shape saturates first, but this isn't the geometry of a multilayer monolithic type.

Comment: Surely the ferrite cores have also magnetic losses, why else magnetic material at all? One could just wrap wire with a badish metal for loss. For inductors, imagine the Z with its roof and bottom flipped "outwards" ;). This is the ideal (and challenging) case for a lossless magnetic. The "magnetic viscosity" is different for beads. At low F, they have no hysteresis, like inductors. But as F rises, their hysteresis opens up. Saturation is of course also a material property, it can require many dozen Tesla for hardmagnetic materials. but you might be right about the geometry as reason in beads.